# how to get text element of column #0 of ttk.Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

assuming a simple table such has:

```
table = ttk.Treeview(self)
table.column('#0', width=50)
table.heading('#0', text='hey')
```

once I set the text to `hey`, I would like to get that value somehow. any way I can access that value?

I can access columns using `table['columns']` but `#0` doesn't show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like it is accessible using `.heading()`

```
table.heading('#0')['text']
```